# C#: Create an array, then mass allocate variables

Tags: c#, arrays

Is it possible to do something like

```
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[100]
    byteArray = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, ... , 0x10}
```

and then set the rest of the variables later?
I would rather avoid using:

```
    byteArray[0] = 0x00;
    byteArray[1] = 0x01;
```

and so on

Sorry, I should have made it more clear     that I want to set maybe half the values at once, then fill the rest in later. I'll go with a list

Comment: Do you mean, is it possible to set all the 100 entries without typing in 100 lines (or the 100 entries as initialization syntax) setting them all?

Comment: You mean values, not variables...

Comment: By the way, the answers will also apply to List<T> which is preferable to an array in nearly every situation I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean can you create an array of 100 items and set 5 of them in-line, something like:

```
int[] i = new int[100] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Then no, you'll get a compiler error:

> > An array initializer of length '100' is expected.

However, you can do in-line initialization of all items:

```
int[] i = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Or more tersely (the compiler can infer this as an `int[]`):

```
var i = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

A half-way house is to instead use a list, which can grow in size later:

```
var i = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
i.Add(6); // etc
```

Then you can change this to an array as needed:

```
var iArray = i.ToArray();
```

There are loads of alternatives, but without knowing much about where these values are coming from, I'm hesitant to keep listing them.

Comment: @Amicable can you start the line with `[] i =`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the array initialization syntax.

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, ... , 0x10};
```

Comment: why are you guys answering without actually reading the question?

Answer (score 1):

While typing out all 100 entries would be, programmatically, the most performant.  If you want to avoid typing them all out, you could do it in a loop:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[100];   
byte currentByte = 0x00;
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    byteArray[i] = currentByte++;
```

Unless you have a variable size, or a 256 byte entries to make, then I suggest doing what the others have posted above by placing it in the array initialization syntax.  If you do have *a lot* of entries, you could write a quick script to *generate* the C# initialization code:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[256];
byte currentByte = 0x00;
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    byteArray[i] = currentByte++;

Console.Write(String.Format("byte[] byteArray = new byte[{0}] {{", byteArray.Length));
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", byteArray));
Console.Write("};");
```

Then you can copy/paste that console result into your C# code file.

EDIT: I feel like a fool.  Of course this is completely *unnecessary* and *dangerous* for lengths greater than 256 as the `currentByte` will just roll over back to 0 because it's a *byte*.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something mutable so I would recommend the following.

```
List<byte> byteArray = new List<byte>() { initialize what you want here };
...
...
byteArray[*n*] = *value*
...
...
byteArray.Add(*value*);
```

This is a lot more flexible. With the list of bytes you can add to it whenever you want and set using the indexer as long as the index exists. Furthermore, you can make that list an array by using the following line of code.

```
byteArray.ToArray();
```

That returns `byte[*length of list*]`

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many items you want to initialize at first, you can create an Dictionary initializer. Example:

```
Dictionary<int,byte> initializer = new Dictionary<int,byte> { {0, 0x01}, {3, 0x04}, {7, 0xFF} .. };
```

Then preinitialize your empty array with simple loop:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[100];

foreach (int key in initializer.Keys)
  byteArray[key] = initializer[key];
```

Comment: Ah I get you, actually a dictionary wouldn't be required, `initializer` could simply be another `byte[]`.

Comment: Of course, good point. I was referring to the OP's original example and must confess I didn't pay direct attention to the values you were using.

Comment: I was also referring to original example which initialized keys 0, 1, 2, 3 then elipsis and then some value of unknown index, so I assummed the indexes are not continuous.